# Make my own HDMI cable with micro usb end

Tags: usb, hdmi, connector, hdtv

Can anyone please tell me how I can splice different cables together to make a HDMI cable with a micro USB end? I need to do this to connect my HTC Desire 626 to my Emerson HDTV to watch Netflix.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here. Google "MHL wiring" or, even better, buy that $2 cable.

Comment: You don't. Depending on the device "USB" cables that connect to HDMI can use a special USB connector that has extra pins embedded in it to allow the transmission of the HDMI signals. You cannot simply cut and splice a standard USB cable to a HDMI in many cases. Buy a cable suitable for your device.

Comment: 5 pin 11 pin? To splice to a regular HDMI cable

Comment: No such (passive) cable could work, because it's not a matter of connectors nor the number of wires.  USB is a protocol for a bus, whereas HDMI is a point-to-point protocol for video+audio.  You are looking for either a USB video adapter or a MHL adapter (or active "cable"), and your phone will have to support such an external device (but for 65% of the Amazon buyers the generic adapter didn't work).

Answer (score 1):

To my surprise such connectors do exist, as for example in Amazon :
[Generic Micro USB to HDMI MHL Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005NG71K8) for $9.
I can also see it has a processor housed in the big box.

So you cannot *splice* these cables - you need an adapter.
Just buy a ready-made one with its dedicated processor.

[image]